# Token Life time

Tags: identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 and Oidc-Client at angular
I have all default settings for Token Lifetime and using implicitflow
 there are 3 tokenlifetime
Accesstokenlifetime, IdtokenLifetime andAuthorizationTokenLifetime

I dont understnad the flow of silentrefresh and how to check it, I made chnages in the lifetime of accesstokenlifetime assuming it will trigger the silentrefresh but it is not triggering it.
second When is the IdTokenLifetime is used and how it impact the authorization

Comment: this might help https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Silent-Refresh-Refreshing-Access-Tokens-when-using-the-Implicit-Flow

Answer (score 0):

The silent refresh being triggered does not depend on the implicit lifetime of any of your tokens. The silent refresh is initiated by the client application and can be done at anytime as long as a cookie based session exists between you and the identity provider. To reiterate what a silent refresh is, it is when a client application opens up an iframe (hidden from the user) to the identity provider and uses the existing cookie session to authenticate and receive a new access and id token.

For your question of why an id token is used and how it impacts *authorization*, I would say it doesn’t at all. Id tokens are only important for the process of *authentication* and not *authorization*.

The difference is that with authorization, the client has been given user permissions sometime in the past which has not yet been revoked. This means that with a refresh token an application can retrieve access tokens and make calls on the user’s behalf without the user actually being logged in to the application. With authentication, the client is ensured that the user has performed some form of authentication within the period of duration of either an identity token expiration or an identity provider session expiration.

The expiration on the id token is in a way saying how long the authentication lasts for before the user is considered unauthenticated. In addition, the field is required to be validated as part of the oidc spec (I believe because of the reasons I stated above) and you cannot create a valid id token without it.